# ASP.NET MVC 5 not sending X-Frame-Options header by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[This article](https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe) seems to suggest that an ASP.NET MVC 5 website automatically sends the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header with the value `SAMEORIGIN`.

I would like that by default, I am observing that for [my website](https://sathyaish.net), it doesn't.

Even adding the following line of code, which would have been unnecessary if the default behavior would have been to send the header, does not seem to send it.

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
```

I can add an action filter attribute and do that explicitly. But I was wondering if I were missing something if I wanted to have that header be sent by default with the `SAMEORIGIN` value?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.4 targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will it add by default if you will use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on a view.
If you don't use it, you need to add this header explicitly e.g. in the action filter attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out soon after writing the question and was going to write a detailed answer myself. Now I don't have to. :-)

Comment: If you have some additional details then you can write one more answer. There is no problem :)

Comment: Nothing additional as such. I was going to explain the whole XSRF thing and the need for the anti forgery token and then what happens when you call the parameterless method (`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`) and that all other parameterized overloads have been deprecated in ASP.NET MVC 5. And when you can call the method and when it will be ineffectual even if you called it.

Comment: I will surely do that in a day or so once I am done with the feature I am working on. Thank you. :-)